# Syntax error on access SQL

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

Same questions, but I can't find my answer there. Even I don't know what's wrong, maybe you can pinpoint it for me:

```vb
If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim query As String = "SELECT pw FROM Password" //or SELECT * FROM Password
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() //error: Syntax error in FROM clause (wtf?)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            If mtPw.Text = dr("pw") Then
                dgvFarrowing.ReadOnly = False
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("wrong pw")
                dgvFarrowing.ReadOnly = True
                mtPw.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: password is the name of the table?? it may be due to the reserved keyword, change the table name if possible then it will work or use [Password]

Comment: sure will post it as answer..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am moving my comment as answer,

Password is Reserverd keyword so it is throwing error

> ```
> Syntax error in FROM clause
> ```

Try to use it within `[]` Square brackets so it takes the value as table like this `[Password]`

But my kind advice would be don't use reserved keywords as the name of the table.

Answer (score 3):

`password` is one of [MS Access reserved words](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx), I'd suggest using square brackets around the table name:

```vb
Dim query As String = "SELECT pw FROM [Password]"
```